# How do I disable the "smart insert" function that is bound to the Tab key in the Visual Studio emacs mode?

Tags: visual-studio, emacs

In both the Visual Studio emacs mode and the default mode the tab key is bound to Edit.InsertTab.  However, in the emacs mode the tab button jumps to where it expects the next line to start instead of inserting a tab.

Is there a way to disable this "smart insert" while keeping the emacs key bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Man, I found it for you :)))
In customization of keyboard shortcuts it is Edit.IncreaseLineIndent.

Set your own key and be happy.
(BTW, I cannot set the Tab key explicitly. Even changing CurrentSettings.vssettings did not help. But it is different story...)

Comment: Cool tip, but this doesn't work if the line is empty (at least in VS 2008).  It just keeps the cursor where it is.

Comment: well... It is the best they have.  
Anyway, emacs mode in VS is not clean.